# Get records by lang_type if not present then get default lang

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I have a requirement like following

```
-------------------------
| Label_Id | Lang_Type |
------------------------- 
| Label1   | EN        |
------------------------- 
| Label2   | EN        |
------------------------- 
| Label2   | DE        |
------------------------- 
| Label3   | EN        |
------------------------- 
| Label4   | EN        |
------------------------- 
| Label4   | DE        |
------------------------- 
| Label5   | EN        |
-------------------------
```

and expected output is that if we query for Lang_Type = DE
then we get one row per Label_Id i.e. if DE is available then return that otherwise return EN row for that label.

```
-------------------------
| Label_Id | Lang_Type |
------------------------- 
| Label1   | EN        |
------------------------- 
| Label2   | DE        |
------------------------- 
| Label3   | EN        |
------------------------- 
| Label4   | DE        |
------------------------- 
| Label5   | EN        |
-------------------------
```

Can someone please guide me on how to fulfill this requirement with current table structure or should the table structures be normalized or something else.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select label_ID,count(label_ID) Label_count into #LabelCount
from table_name
group by label_ID


select O.label_ID,O.Lang_Type into #O2
from table_name O
inner join #LabelCount LC on O.label_ID=LC.label_ID
where LC.Label_count=2 AND O.Lang_Type='DE'

select O.label_ID,O.Lang_Type into #O3
from table_name O
inner join #LabelCount LC on O.label_ID=LC.label_ID
where LC.Label_count=1

select * from (
select label_ID,Lang_Type from #O2
UNION
select label_ID,Lang_Type from #O3 ) AS ANSWER

DROP TABLE #LabelCount
DROP TABLE #O2
DROP TABLE #O3
```

This might give you the required output

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think this might give the desired output but this might be a bit slow as we do a lot of select. Do u see any other way which less computation may b by changing the table structure or anything else.

Comment: Converted your code into the pl/sql and it works like charm.